# Trouble making ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code is working fine, but my main component is too overwhelmed with the function *"renderCadastros"*.

**How can i make the function *"renderCadastros"* a child component and use it where i have "{Cadastros.map(renderCadastros)}" and keep the code running the same?**

I'll still have to call the function *"removerCadastro"* from this parent component when the *"renderCadastros"* component is created.

Parent component:

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Table, Jumbotron, Button, Badge} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Formulario from './Formulario'

function App() {
  
  const [Cadastros, setCadastros] = useState([{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Francisca Julia da Costa",
    "cpf": "457.696.936-65",
    "rg": "47.360.897-2",
    "data_nasc": "23/03/1944",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Noah Felipe Silva",
    "cpf": "956.531.431-70",
    "rg": "40.974.782-8",
    "data_nasc": "11/07/1964",
    "sexo": "Masculino"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "Alícia Rosângela Melo",
    "cpf": "066.291.353-18",
    "rg": "36.214.141-1",
    "data_nasc": "18/02/1978",
    "sexo": "Feminino"
  }]) 
  
  function atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro){
    setCadastros(cadastrosAtuais => {
      return [...cadastrosAtuais, novoCadastro]
    })
  }

  function idExiste(novaId){
    return Cadastros.some(cadastro=> cadastro.id == novaId)
  }

  function removerCadastro(index){
    setCadastros(Cadastros.filter(cadastro => cadastro.id != index))
  }

  function renderCadastros(cadastro, index){
    return(
    <tr id={cadastro.id} key={index}>
        <td>{cadastro.id}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.nome}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.cpf}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.rg}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.data_nasc}</td>
        <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.sexo}</td>
        <td align="center"><Button  onClick={()=>removerCadastro(cadastro.id)} variant="danger">Excluir</Button></td>
    </tr>)
    }

  return (
  <Jumbotron style={{background: 'transparent'}}> 
    <Formulario idExiste={idExiste} atualizarCadastros={atualizarCadastros} />
    
    <h4>
    Quantidade de registros: <Badge variant="info">{Cadastros.length}</Badge>
    </h4>
    
    <Table striped bordered hover size='sm'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>CPF</th>
          <th>RG</th>
          <th>Nascimento</th>
          <th>Sexo</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {Cadastros.map(renderCadastros)}
      </tbody>
    </Table>
  </Jumbotron>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Form component that i managed to create:

```js
import './App.css';
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {Button, Form, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'

function Formulario ({atualizarCadastros, idExiste}){
  const refId = useRef()
  const refNome = useRef()
  const refCpf = useRef()
  const refRg = useRef()
  const refNascimento = useRef()
  const refSexo = useRef()

  function registrarCadastros(){
    const id = refId.current.value
    const nome = refNome.current.value
    const cpf = refCpf.current.value
    const rg = refRg.current.value
    const nascimento = refNascimento.current.value
    const sexo = refSexo.current.value

    const novoCadastro = {'id': id, 'nome': nome, 'cpf': cpf, 'rg': rg, 'data_nasc': nascimento, 'sexo': sexo}

    if(id == '' || nome == '' || cpf == '' || rg == '' || nascimento == '' || sexo == '' ){
      window.alert("Existem campos em branco!")
    }

    else if(idExiste(id)){
      window.alert("Id já cadastrada!")
    }

    else{
    atualizarCadastros(novoCadastro)

    refId.current.value = null
    refNome.current.value = null
    refCpf.current.value = null
    refRg.current.value = null
    refNascimento.current.value = null
    refSexo.current.value = null
    }
  }

  return(
    <div key="formulario">
    <Form>
    <Form.Row>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Identificação</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refId} placeholder="Id" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Nome Completo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refNome} placeholder="João Silva" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>CPF</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refCpf} placeholder="000.000.000-00" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>RG</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refRg} placeholder="0.000.000" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Data de Nascimento</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refNascimento} placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" />
      </Col>
      <Col>
        <Form.Label>Sexo</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control ref={refSexo} placeholder="Masculino/Feminino" />
      </Col>
    </Form.Row>
    </Form>
    <div  style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Button onClick={registrarCadastros} style={{margin: '10px'}} variant="info">Cadastrar</Button>
    </div> 
  </div>
  )  
}

export default Formulario
```

I'm a beginner ReactJS student so any advices would be apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a react component and pass `props` into it.
For example in this case, you can create a new component like.

```js
function Cadastros({ cadastro }) {
    return (
        <div>
            return(
            <tr id={cadastro.id}>
                <td>{cadastro.id}</td>
                <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.nome}</td>
                <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.cpf}</td>
                <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.rg}</td>
                <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.data_nasc}</td>
                <td contentEditable="true" suppressContentEditableWarning={true}>{cadastro.sexo}</td>
                <td align="center"><Button onClick={() => removerCadastro(cadastro.id)} variant="danger">Excluir</Button></td>
            </tr>)
        </div>
    )
}
```

And then replace

```js
  <tbody>
      {Cadastros.map(renderCadastros)}
      </tbody>
```

with

```
<tbody>
{
  Cadastros.map((c,i) => <Cadastro cadastro={c} key={i} />) }
</tbody>
```